# Why after double clicking in a field displays data in angularjs page

Tags: angularjs

I am fetching data from angularjs controller:

```
    $scope.findEmployeeById = function() {

        if( !angular.isUndefined($location.search().employeeId) ) {
            $.getJSON( servicefindEmployeeById+$location.search().employeeId, function( data ) {
                $scope.employee = data;

            });
        }

    }
```

And I render the **$scope.employee** on employee-detail.html page, this way:

```
<html>
    <body ng-init="findEmployeeById()">
            <input type="text" ng-model="employee.firstName"/>
    </body>
</htm>
```

> **Problem Statement**:
>   It displays data only after I click in the field and then click outside the field.

Please enlighten why I am facing the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: when you are calling `findEmployeeById` funciton

Comment: where is `findEmployeeById()`

Comment: I think this could be a digest problem. Try using `$http.get(json_url).then((res) => {$scope.employee = res.data;})`

Comment: Another way is `$scope.$apply()`.

Comment: findEmployeeById in on ng-init of the employ-detail.html @Sravan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

Since you are using `$.getJSON` and wrapping your angular `$scope` inside it, the **digest cycle is unable to read that change.**

**Solution 1 (preferred):**

**Use, `angular's`  `$http` instead of `$.getJSON`**

For json you can use **`jsonp`** method type.

```
$scope.findEmployeeById = function() {
    if( !angular.isUndefined($location.search().employeeId) ) {
        $http({method: 'JSONP', url: servicefindEmployeeById+$location.search().employeeId}).
            then(function(data, status) {
                $scope.employee = data;
            }).
            catch(function(data, status) {
                console.log(data || "Request failed");
        });
    }
}
```

[**Here is the documentation for $http**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp)

---

**Solution 2 (not preferred for performance reasons still may work):**

If you want to use `$.getJSON` then, you can use `$scope.$apply` and wrap `$scope.employee = data;` inside it.

```
$scope.findEmployeeById = function() {
    if( !angular.isUndefined($location.search().employeeId) ) {
        $.getJSON( servicefindEmployeeById+$location.search().employeeId, function( data ) {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                   $scope.employee = data;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

**Note for solution2:**

> The `$scope.$apply(function(){ $scope.employee = data; });` runs only
>   for `employee` since I wrapped in a function, and it is way better
>   compared to  `$scope.$apply()` which runs the complete digest cycle
>   again.

Answer (score 1):

inject `$timeout` into your controller

```
$scope.findEmployeeById = function() {

    if( !angular.isUndefined($location.search().employeeId) ) {
        $.getJSON( servicefindEmployeeById+$location.search().employeeId, function( data ) {
            $timeout(function(){
                $scope.employee = data;
            });

        });
    }

}
```

Or you can use `$scope.$apply()`

```
$scope.findEmployeeById = function() {

        if( !angular.isUndefined($location.search().employeeId) ) {
            $.getJSON( servicefindEmployeeById+$location.search().employeeId, function( data ) {
                $scope.$apply(function(){ 
                    $scope.employee = data; 
                 });
            });
        }

    }
```